# How to convert protobuf wireformat to JSON with just a message descriptor?

Tags: json, go, reflection, protocol-buffers, descriptor

Normally, to convert a protobuf message from wire format to JSON, you simply unmarshal the wire format into a `proto.Message` whose dynamic type is a concrete Go type (generated by protoc-gen-go), and then unmarshal that to JSON with the `protojson` package.

I would like to know how to do the same if you *don't* have a concrete Go type, but a `protoreflect.MessageDescriptor` instead. The descriptor should have all the information necessary to parse the wire format and construct a JSON (or other formats) from it, but I can't seem to find an API for that. It seems like I need something like the following:

```golang
func UnmarshalFromWire(b []byte, desc protoreflect.MessageDescriptor) (protoreflect.Message, error)

func MarshalToJSON(m protoreflect.Message) ([]byte, error)
```

Is there an API like that or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`dynamicpb`](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/types/dynamicpb?tab=doc) module does the first part (from `MessageDescriptor` to `proto.Message`, not `protoreflect.Message`).

```
func UnmarshalFromWire(b []byte, desc protoreflect.MessageDescriptor) (proto.Message, error) {
  m := dynamicpb.NewMessage(desc)
  if err := proto.Unmarshal(b, m); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return m, nil
}
```

The second part is just your standard `protojson.Marshal` - since you now have a perfectly valid `proto.Message`.

Comment: Actually, `*dynamicpb.Message` implements both `proto.Message` and `protoreflect.Message`.